# package or namespace load failed for ‘mxnet’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]): object 'vI' not found

Tags: r

Can anybody explain the error and how to solve it?

When I run `sessionInfo()`, I got as:

```
attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] EBImage_4.22.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
```

> Error in x[["Version"]] : subscript out of bounds
>   In addition: Warning messages:
>   1: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
>     DESCRIPTION file of package 'purrr' is missing or broken
>   2: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
>     DESCRIPTION file of package 'RCurl' is missing or broken

Comment: What happened before you got the error?

Comment: Start a new session, and run `install.packages(c("purrr", "RCurl"))`.  That might fix them, and then whatever you were trying to do might work.

Comment: "purrr" and "RCurl" package are successfully installed but after restarting the session got another error as:  cannot open URL 'https://github.com/dmlc/drat/blob/gh-pages/bin/windows/contrib/3.4:': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
> install.packages("mxnet")

Comment: is there any other source for package "mxnet". Earlier I was able to install from source  source("https://dmlc.github.io/drat/bin/windows/contrib/3.5:") but not got error: HTTP status was '404 Not Found' > install.packages("mxnet")